# Duplicate binaries in Erlang process info

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm trying to figure out how much binary memory a process is holding onto by summing the results from `Process.info(pid, :binary)`, but it's giving me inaccurate results. On one machine with 128GB of RAM it says a process is using over 1TB of memory.

I think I've tracked the problem down to `Process.info` returning a list that contains the same binaries multiple times.

Here's an Elixir script that demonstrates what I'm seeing. The "junk_file" is a file I created that has a bunch of JSON objects with one object per line.

```
result =
  Stream.iterate(0, & &1 + 1)
  |> Stream.take(10_000)
  |> Flow.from_enumerable(max_demand: 1)
  |> Flow.flat_map(fn _ ->
    File.read!("junk_file") |> String.split("\n")
  end)
  |> Enum.to_list()

system_binary_bytes =
  :erlang.memory() |> Keyword.get(:binary)

{:binary, binaries} =
  Process.info(self(), :binary)

binary_ids =
  Enum.map(binaries, &elem(&1, 0))

binary_bytes =
  Enum.map(binaries, &elem(&1, 1))
  |> Enum.sum()

unique_binary_bytes =
  Enum.uniq_by(binaries, fn {id, _, _} -> id end)
  |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))
  |> Enum.sum()

unique_ids =
  MapSet.new(binary_ids)

unique_ids_times_ref =
  Enum.uniq_by(binaries, fn {id, _, _} -> id end)
  |> Enum.map(& elem(&1, 2))
  |> Enum.sum()

IO.puts("binary_ids           #{Enum.count(binary_ids)}")
IO.puts("unique_ids           #{Enum.count(unique_ids)}")
IO.puts("binary_bytes         #{binary_bytes}")
IO.puts("unique_bytes         #{unique_binary_bytes}")
IO.puts("unique_ids_times_ref #{unique_ids_times_ref}")
IO.puts("system_binary_bytes  #{system_binary_bytes}")

Enum.count(result)
```

Here are the results from an example run:

```
binary_ids           2166004
unique_ids           10003
binary_bytes         373817119944
unique_bytes         1725843360
unique_ids_times_ref 2166009
system_binary_bytes  1731508128
```

As you can see, quite a few ids are repeated and summing the reported memory of each binary after deduplicating them by binary id results in a total much closer to the system total.

Is it safe to assume that binary ids are unique and can be used to dedup the list? Is this the correct way to resolve my problem?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you are abusing pipe operator. `Enum.map(binaries, &elem(&1, 1)) |> Enum.sum()` should be written as `binaries |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1)) |> Enum.sum()` here and everywhere.